# How to run E2E test with Cypress if backend and frontend are on different repos?

Tags: testing, bitbucket, cypress, e2e-testing, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a React frontend and a Node backend, I've made several E2E tests with Cypress for the frontend and run them locally. I love how end to end testing allows me to catch errors in the frontend as well as on the backend! so I'd like to have a way to run them automatically when sending a PR.

I'm using bitbucket pipelines, and I've configured it to run the `npm test` command which works perfectly to run my unit tests, but what I still don't understand is how to be able to run my Cypress tests automatically, because I'd need to have access to the backend repository from my pipeline that runs on the frontend repo.

---

**What I've tried**

I've read the [documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/continuous-integration/bitbucket-pipelines#Testing-in-Chrome-and-Firefox-with-Cypress-Docker-Images) and played with the [example repo](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-realworld-app), but I still don't understand how could I automate running my tests, on the example both backend and frontend are on the same repository.

---

I'm sorry if this is a vague question, I just *don't* seem to get if this is even possible with bitbucket pipelines, if it's not, what other tool could help me run my Cypress test in a similar way that I do locally? (running both backend and frontend).

I've really tried to search for an answer to this, maybe it's too obvious and I'm just missing something but I don't seem to find anything on the internet about this, any help will be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your frontend and backend are versioned in different repositories, then you have to check out at least one of the two repositories (e.g. the other for which the pipeline is not currently being executed) during the pipeline execution to get access to the code and thus have the possibility to start frontend and backend together locally to run your tests.

This question has also already been asked and answered here:
https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Access-multiple-Bitbucket-repositories-from-a-single-Pipeline/qaq-p/1783419